# How to implement a NashornScriptEngine?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

In my on-going project, we are going to use a Nashorn, so I need to create this script engine. Anyone can suggest, what are the steps involved to create a `NashornScriptEngine`? Please specify the steps.

Comment: As you seem to begin using Nashorn, I suggest you read [this Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html). It will get you started.

Comment: gone through this article earlier. I am planning to create our own script engine. As per my understand need to write a absractScriptengine and ScriptEngineFactory. is it right way to proceed? Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Example :
you can follow my example  @github https://github.com/jamesmedice/Spring-boot---React-js

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine;

    private ThreadLocal<NashornScriptEngine> engineHolder = new ThreadLocal<NashornScriptEngine>() {
    @Override
    protected NashornScriptEngine initialValue() {
        NashornScriptEngine nashornScriptEngine = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
        nashornScriptEngine.eval(read("static/nashorn-polyfill.js"));
        nashornScriptEngine.eval(read("your_js_file.js")); 
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return nashornScriptEngine;
    }
    };


private Reader read(String path) {
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
return new InputStreamReader(in);
}
```